# Deck Shuffling Method

Tags: vb.net, playing-cards, shuffle

Just wondering if you guys think this is a good way to shuffle a deck or a bad way. Updated to show the GetRandom function as requested.

```
Private Sub DeckShuffle()
        ' shuffles the deck 4 times.
        For shufflingCards As Integer = 0 To 3
            ' goes through each card and changes position once each time it goes through shufflingCards
            For shuffleEachCard As Integer = 0 To 51
                ' gets a random number 0 - 51
                Dim placeHolder As Integer = GetRandom(0, 51)
                ' creates a temporary card for swapping cards
                Dim tempCard As Card = deck(placeHolder)
                ' makes the random number card now the card we were shuffling
                deck(placeHolder) = deck(shuffleEachCard)
                ' replaces the card we were shuffling with the one we were saving as a temporary
                deck(shuffleEachCard) = tempCard
            Next
        Next
    End Sub

' Gets a random number for shuffling.
Private Function GetRandom(ByVal Min As Integer, ByVal Max As Integer) As Integer
    Static Generator As System.Random = New System.Random()
    Return Generator.Next(Min, Max)
End Function
```

Comment: You only need one pass through the deck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need to shuffle the deck 4 times. For a use case of shuffling a deck of cards using the `System.Random` once should be sufficient.

But there is still something to say about the `GetRandom()` method:

- based on the [.NET naming Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) method arguments should be named using `camelCase` casing. Although VB.NET is case-insensitive you should improve your coding style by applying the guidelines because other developers will expect it.
- the declaration and initialisation of `Static Generator As System.Random = New System.Random()` could be simplified like `Static generator As New System.Random()` which takes into account naming local variables using `camelCase` casing as well.

---

#### DeckShuffle()

- If this method is part of a `Deck` class you should just name it `Shuffle` otherwise `ShuffleDeck` would be better because methods should be named using verbs or verb phrases.
- The inner loop variable `shuffleEachCard` isn't named good as well. `currentCard` would be more significant (you can't shuffle a single card).
- `Dim placeHolder As Integer = GetRandom(0, 51)` will get you a random number in the range of `0..50` because the `maxValue` parameter of `Random.Next` is exclusive. Hence you should change it to `GetRandom(0, 52)` to get a random number in the range `0..51`. In addition `randomCardNumber` would be a better name.

Comment: Wow, thank you for answering my review. I thought this thread was d.a.d. 

I'll implement the changes like you have suggested :)

Answer (score 2):

Another way to shuffle a deck is to start of with your full deck (oldDeck) and an empty deck (newDeck). This uses the same random generator function in the OP.  I haven't tried to properly code this because the algorithm is the important message.

```
While size of oldDeck > 0
  chosenCard = getrandom(0,size of oldDeck-1)
  remove chosenCard from oldDeck ' reduces the size of oldDeck by 1
  append chosenCard to newDeck
'Wend
return newDeck ' or reassign newDeck to oldDeck, depending on the broader context
```

This algorithm would be particularly useful if a class of `Deck` existed, and it could be a member function as noted in the previous reply. You could then consider having a class of `Card` which includes a suit and value. A `Deck` would then be a collection of `Card`s, and the built-in collection functions become your friends. Of course, this amount of effort depends on what you are going to do with your `Deck`.

Answer (score 1):

@Brandon, you only need one pass through the deck.

A question: why don't you try the Fisher-Yates shuffle?

Pseudocode from Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle):

```
-- To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..n-1):
for i from 0 to n−2 do
     j ← random integer such that i ≤ j < n
     exchange a[i] and a[j]
```

Your code would look like this:

```
        For shuffleEachCard As Integer = 0 To 50
            ' gets a random number 
            Dim placeHolder As Integer = GetRandom(i, 52)
            ' creates a temporary card for swapping cards
            Dim tempCard As Card = deck(placeHolder)
            ' makes the random number card now the card we were shuffling
            deck(placeHolder) = deck(shuffleEachCard)
            ' replaces the card we were shuffling with the one we were saving as a temporary
            deck(shuffleEachCard) = tempCard
        Next
```